# calculating Y value given X using slope from plot/datapoints

Tags: r, plot, algebra

I'm trying to figure out what the easiest way of doing this might be.
I could have various data-table lengths and I want to automatically fill in the missing values with the slope of the connecting datapoints.  I'm just not sure the easiest way to do this programmatically.

I imagine there is some sort of thing like this that I could do but again I don't know how to apply this or if there is an easy loop/dplyr/ other function that solves this problem.

**Basically** if there was a line plot, where would each of the points be as the line crosses over that X/index value?  thats what I want.

```
        lm(y~index)$coef[[2]] * index + lm(y~index)$coef[[1]]
```

Two examples:

```
        df = data.frame(index = 1:6, y = c(10,NA,20,NA,NA,2) 
        df2 = data.frame(index = 1:8, y=c(NA,NA,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,18)

     solutions:
 df = data.frame(index = 1:6, y = c(10,15, 20,14,8,2)#slope of 5 and then -6
 df2 = data.frame(index = 1:8, y=c(NA,NA,2,5.2,8.4,11.6,14.8,18) #slope of 3.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `approx` along with the argument `n` specifying how many data points linear interpolations will occur. It requires, as you have done, that there are least two complete cases of (x,y) pairs.

```
data.frame(approx(df, n = nrow(df)))

  x  y
1 1 10
2 2 15
3 3 20
4 4 14
5 5  8
6 6  2
```

Comment: In the df2 case, the `NA` values will be interpolated as well, if you do it with the `n` argument. The better way would be to specify the desired interpolation points with `which(is.na(df2$y))`

Comment: Then, having saved the points in `interp.pts`, replace those values as follows: `df2$y[interp.pts] <- approx(df2$index,df2$y, xout=interp.pts)$y`

Comment: @EdwardCarney makes a good point, but there is still the problem of interpolation of the endpoints even if you specify which points to interpolate specifically.

Comment: Extrapolation to end point(s), as in df2, above, would be "subject to greater uncertainty and a higher risk of producing meaningless results," as is suggested in the Wikipedia entry on that topic. In addition, the quality of data sampling and one's knowledge of "data behavior" play a role in deciding whether or not to rely on extrapolation. In such a case as @scbears88 presents, my preference would be to leave the end points unmodified (that is, NA) to remind myself of the intrinsic problems in estimating their values.

Comment: Totally agree, I wouldn't estimate NA points outside the domain either. I just thought that it warranted mentioning.

Comment: thank you shayaa, i saw the approx function but I guess i didn't notice the parameters

Comment: @EdwardCarney   - sorry where exactly would I use the which(is.na(df2$y))?

Comment: `interp.pts <- which(is.na(df2$y))`